# How to store NULL values in an interval partitioned table in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We use partitioning to be able to delete old data (Oracle calls this [ILM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/part_lifecycle.htm)).
There is a column with the "best before date", after which the partition will be dropped.

To avoid having to add partitions manually (or per script), we use interval partitioning:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  --... other columns ...
  t DATE
) PARTITION BY RANGE (t) INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(7, 'DAY')) (
  PARTITION PRE2018 VALUES LESS THAN (DATE '2018-01-01')
);

INSERT INTO my_table(id, t) VALUES (1, SYSDATE);
-- 1 row inserted.
```

... which works fine, but we cannot leave the partitioning date to `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(id, t) VALUES (2, NULL);
-- ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: You can't, if you need the date being nullable, you will probably need to add another date column (e.g. createDate default SYSDATE) and partition on that.

Comment: @BigMike thanks for the confirmation. createDate is not an option, as our column is the deletion date (as I've written in the question)

Comment: null not possible in partition column. you set not null and default some in applicable value like '01-01-1900' 
assign this to another temp partition

Comment: **NULL** as key for interval partitioning is not [allowed](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-C121EA1B-2725-4464-B2C9-EEDE0C3C95AB.htm) *NULL values cannot be stored in the partitioning key column when using interval partitioning.*

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this for example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    --... other columns ...
    t TIMESTAMP(0),
    PARTITION_KEY TIMESTAMP(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(t, TIMESTAMP '2999-01-01 00:00:00')) VIRTUAL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (PARTITION_KEY) INTERVAL( NUMTODSINTERVAL(7, 'DAY')) ( 
    PARTITION PRE2018 VALUES LESS THAN (TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
);
```

It should be simple to address it like `PARTITION FOR (TIMESTAMP '2999-01-01 00:00:00')`

Perhaps you can also use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(t, TIMESTAMP '1900-01-01 00:00:00'))` depending what fits better to your logic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, interesting approach. Out of interest, would partition pruning work with a virtual column? (In our case the column is the deletion date, so it is highly unlikely that the date is included in a query).

Comment: Most likely not, you need to modify your query, e.g. `select * from my_table partition for (TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 00:00:00') WHERE T = ...`. But it should work if you create a (local) index on your date column.

Comment: BTW, thanks for using `TIMESTAMP`. While reading up before writing this questino I stumbled over the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#CACHFHHF) saying one can only use `NUMBER` or `DATE` for interval partitioning. Is there a reason why you pick `TIMESTAMP` instead of `DATE`?

Comment: @wolφi, not really, I am just used to it. If I deal with `INTERVAL` values then I prefer `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Comment: @wolφi Pruning on virtual column wor fine, you must user the virtual column formula in the predicate such as: `where COALESCE(t, TIMESTAMP '2999-01-01 00:00:00') = TIMESTAMP '2018-01-01 00:00:00'`

Answer (score 0):

Use an On Insert Trigger if Key value NULL then it will insert a default value or SYSDATE

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).