# Concurrent queries to insert data in partitioned table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, partitioning, database-administration, oracle11gr2

I'm running concurrent insert queries (12 queries at the same time) through an ETL tool to insert data into a partitioned table in Oracle.

The table definition is

```
CREATE TABLE CUST_TRAN
(
TRAN_SEQ_NO NUMBER(20,0)
, TRAN_DATE DATE
) 
TABLESPACE USERS
STORAGE (INITIAL 256K NEXT 256K)
PARTITION BY RANGE (TRAN_DATE) 
INTERVAL(NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY')) 
(  
   PARTITION CUST_TRAN_p_old VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-2008', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
)
```

The 12 queries are running for 4 different dates (3 queries for each date). So, the 12 queries are trying to insert into 4 partitions.  Here is the sample insert query -

```
insert into cust_tran 
select a.tran_seq_no, trunc(a.tran_datetime) as tran_date
from table_a a
    inner join table_b b on a.store = b.store
        and a.tran_seq_no = b.tran_seq_no
        and trunc(a.tran_datetime) = to_date('2018-01-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        and a.tran_type in ('SALE')
```

However, I keep running into one of the following issues -

1) I get this error - `ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions`

Or

2) The job runs fine without any error but inserts data into the CUST_TRAN_SUMM_p_old partition with a weird date that did not exist in any of the source queries and that date doesn’t exist in the source tables. The exact value of that weird date is hard to tell because when I use SQL Developer and format the date to be displayed as YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (in Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS), it displays null but when I change the display format to DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS, it displays 29-NOV-01 22:58:59. When I use DBeaver, it displays as 10101-11-29 22:58:59. When I use Toad for Oracle, it is displayed as 1/1/0001.

The first issue is really weird because I'm supplying the date in the filter and there is no way it can pickup another date that is not in the filter. Plus, I'm running this after freshly creating the table. So, it's impossible that it has reached the maximum number of partitions (1,023,999).

Second issue is equally weird.

Is this a bug in Oracle? Is there some setting in Oracle that needs to be changed? Is it wrong to insert data using concurrent insert queries into a partitioned table?

Comment: As far as I can tell,there should be no problem (of your kind) if there are multiple *sources* of the insert operation. Did you check the source? What is it, anyway? Can you find date "10101-11-29" in there?

Comment: This definitely sounds weird and shouldn't be happening. The good news is, it almost certainly isn't happening. But you will need to post a reproducible test case if you want us to explain what is actually occurring.

Comment: What is `10101`? - it can't be a year nor a month nor a day.... Post your date in format `DD-MM-YYYY`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber -  When I use SQL Developer and format the date to be displayed as YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS, it displays null. When I use DBeaver, it displays as 10101-11-29 22:58:59.

Answer (score 0):

One thing at least seem to be clear. The error you mentioned is

```
 ORA-14300: partitioning key maps to a partition outside maximum permitted number of partitions
```

which happen when you insert the value `NULL` in the partition key of an interval partition table.

Simple try this INSERT

```
 insert into CUST_TRAN (TRAN_SEQ_NO,TRAN_DATE) Values(1,null);
```

There is no simple workaround for this problem, most often some *strange date* (such as 01.01.2999) is used to substitue the missing date - see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190663/how-to-store-null-values-in-an-interval-partitioned-table-in-oracle)

Here I would start the investigation - assuming that THE *strange date* you observe is such a substitute for missing of invalid dates.

It is not enough to investigate the source databases, a typical ETL process is a bit more complex that a simple insert. You must check the code of the ETL script to see if there is such date manipulation.

To your observed date `10101-11-29` - the allowed [range for years](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT413) exclude 10101 as a year.

> Oracle Database can store dates in the Julian era, ranging from January 1, 4712 BCE through December 31, 9999 CE (Common Era, or 'AD'). Unless BCE ('BC' in the format mask) is specifically used, CE date entries are the default.

From the fact, that this date is in the `old` partition (i.e. less then 2008), I'd assume that it is the November of the year 29 - `DATE'0029-11-01'` and the DAY is somehow concatenated with other string *on output*.

Comment: I can tell you one thing for sure - there is nothing wrong with the ETL tool or the process. I did create a very simple ETL process without any variables. I've hard-coded all the values and dates. 12 insert queries running concurrently via the ETL tool.